# Can Python program developed on 64-bit Windows run on all version of Windows?

Tags: python

I have developed a python application with 64-bit Windows 8 *(the non metro version which looks like Windows 7 interface)*. I want to distribute it to all version of 64-bit Windows such as Windows XP, Windows 7 and etc. Is it possible for program developed with python to do that? Also, can the software run on 32-bit Windows os as well?

Comment: Your python code doesn't run on your OS, but inside the python "VM". As long as you don't do any 64-bit related sys-calls, everything should work. But why don't you just try it out?

Answer (score 4):

Well-written pure Python programs (just `.py` files) are extraordinarily portable across all platforms.  If you're using some way of packaging your program in a Windows executable (`.exe` file), then you have worlds of other possible problems.

There are cases where a 64-bit program won't work on a 32-bit system, such as if your program uses massive data structures and you simply run out of address space on a 32-bit system.  But, barring things like that, you should be fine.

If you want more specifics, I'm afraid **you'll** need to be more specific ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not used any 64 bit specific items the your code should run fine on all versions of windows from source code with a minimum installation of python and the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For the python code itself, this won't very much be the problem, python code is quite portable.

However, you do need to using some porting tool specific for 32bit Windows to convert .py to .exe.

check this, http://www.pyinstaller.org/